# Integrating a file browser into ckeditor & CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-1.3, ckeditor

recently found an article in http://hashtwo.com/blog/integrating-a-file-browser-into-ckeditor-cakephp to integrate a file browser into ckeditor (file manager of [core five labs](http://labs.corefive.com/Projects/FileManager/) )

I followed the steps but i get an error when I click the browse server button,

Missing Controller: 
Error: CkeditorController could not be found.

Comment: have you previously integrated CKeditor with Cake? That tutorial is just for the file browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error at some point during my setup, but I don't seem to recall what was it and how I fixed it. Let me know if my next solution does not fix your problem and I will investigate a little more:

1. First I followed the following tutorial which worked well, but missed the Authentication part: http://labs.corefive.com/projects/filemanager/
2. Then I used the tutorial you referenced, except for the last section of code provided. Instead I added the following code directly to my view page: `admin_add.ctp`

   ```
   <?php echo $form->textarea('body', array(/*'class'=>'ckeditor', */'id' => 'body', 'class' => 'body')) ?>
   <?php
       include_once 'ckeditor/ckeditor.php' ;
       //require_once 'ckfinder/ckfinder.php' ;
       //$initialValue = 'Default value goes here' ;
       $ckeditor = new CKEditor() ;
       $ckeditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/' ;
       $ckeditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '/ckeditor/filemanager/index.html';
       $ckeditor->config['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = '/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/filemanager.php';
       $ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = '/ckeditor/filemanager/index.html?type=Images';
       $ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageUploadUrl'] = '/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/filemanager.php?command=QuickUpload&type;=Images';

       $ckeditor->config['filebrowserWindowWidth'] = '800';
       //CKFinder::SetupCKEditor( $ckeditor,'/ckfinder/' ) ;

               // This will replace CakePHP textarea listed above.
       $ckeditor->replace('body');
   ?>
   ```

Also, for the Auth Section of his tutorial I changed it to match my requirements:

```
function auth() {
    session_name("CAKEPHP");
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['Auth']['User']) )
    {
        //Since CKEditor for me is only used in the admin section
        //I make sure only admins can access it, group_id=1
        if($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['group_id'] == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: THanks your code works, but also i had to change in config.js to the full path.. to this... config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/blog2/app/webroot/js/ckeditor/Filemanager/index.html?type=Images';

Comment: Hey. I just placed my application online this weekend and I noticed also that I had to change the section of code you referenced above to full path, maybe because it is a shared hosting. Anyway, I am glad I was able to help... CakePHP Rules!

Answer (score 1):

If it tries to find a controller this means it can not access the editors file or folder and instead the dispatcher of CakePHP gets the request and tries to load a fckeditor controller.

This means you'll need to place the editor in the right directory (for example app/webroot/fckedtor/) or use the correct url to access it.